Usage of にする with a noun?

うん、店変わったから。後輩の客にしてる。

The character is talking to a friend. He says he changed shop and then this. What does "にしてる" mean in the context of dealing with a client? I know にする but I don't see how it works with a noun?

This question is similar to: とする・にする before a noun. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This example sounds ambiguous. Could you provide any previous context about what they were talking about?
